# Reject incoming call while on waiting

Tags: iphone, ios, call

If I get a call while I'm busy with another call (call waiting, normal call, not FaceTime), can I reject that incoming call?

I'm using an iPhone 5 running iOS 8.2.

I didn't try anything till now, and I don't want to turn the call waiting off. I want to decide whether to accept or reject the incoming call *while* I'm on another call.

The screen that appears when I receive another call has only three options:

1. Hold the current call and ANSWER the coming one
2. Hang up the current call and ANSWER the coming one
3. Reply with a message to the caller (of the new call)
   none of the options actually allows me to REJECT the incoming new call and keep the current one going

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just press on "send to voicemail" (the middle option) and the call will be rejected.

Comment: I was thinking how to avoid costing the caller the cost of the call. Just reject it!

Answer (score 1):

If you go into settings > phone and turn off call waiting then any calls you receive when you are busy with another call will be auto-rejected and sent to voicemail or other similar service. If you leave call waiting on, when the second call comes through you'll be able to reject it yourself or put the current call on hold to switch to the new call.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I don't want to turn the waiting off. And I'm NOT able to reject the incoming call (no option shows for that)

Answer (score 1):

Just press the power button two times to cut the second call (or )press the voice mail button to cut the second call as long as if you don’t set voice msg then the second caller won’t be charged.